# How do I ensure that BeautifulSoup does not look at commas as tabs

Tags: python, html, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have created a **scraping** code to take information from a local newspaper site. I have two existing problems with the current code.

1. When it retrieves the paragraph data, and saves it to the CSV. it recognises "," as breaks and save the relevant data in the adjacent cell. How do I stop this from happening?
2. I want them to the **scraped** information in rows. i.e paragraph, title, weblink

Code below;

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq

page_url = "https://neweralive.na/today/"

ne_url = "https://neweralive.na/posts/"

uClient = uReq(page_url)

page_soup = soup(uClient.read(), "html.parser")
uClient.close()


containers = page_soup.findAll("article", {"class": "post-item"})

filename = "newera.csv"
headers = "paragraph,title,link\n"

f = open(filename, "w")
f.write(headers)

for container in containers:
    paragraph_container = container.findAll("p", {"class": "post-excerpt"})
    paragraph = paragraph_container[0].text

    title_container = container.findAll("h3", {"class": "post-title"})
    title = title_container[0].text
    weblink = ne_url + title_container[0].a["href"]

    f.write(paragraph + "," + title + "," + weblink + "\n")

f.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [built-in `csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/csv.html#module-csv) to write well-formed CSV with quotes around strings that need those (e.g. those containing commas).

While at it, I refactored your code to use reusable functions:

- `get_soup_from_url()` downloads an URL and gets a BeautifulSoup out of it
- `parse_today_page()` is a generator function that can walk through that soup and return dicts of each article
- The main code now just uses `csv.DictWriter` on the opened file; the dicts parsed are printed to the console for debugging ease and fed to the CSV writer for output.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
import csv


base_url = "https://neweralive.na/posts/"


def get_soup_from_url(url):
    resp = urlopen(url)
    page_soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.read(), "html.parser")
    resp.close()
    return page_soup


def parse_today_page(page_soup):
    for container in page_soup.findAll("article", {"class": "post-item"}):
        paragraph_container = container.findAll(
            "p", {"class": "post-excerpt"}
        )
        paragraph = paragraph_container[0].text
        title_container = container.findAll("h3", {"class": "post-title"})
        title = title_container[0].text
        weblink = base_url + title_container[0].a["href"]
        yield {
            "paragraph": paragraph,
            "title": title.strip(),
            "link": weblink,
        }


print("Downloading...")
page_soup = get_soup_from_url("https://neweralive.na/today/")

with open("newera.csv", "w") as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, ["paragraph", "title", "link"])
    writer.writeheader()
    for entry in parse_today_page(page_soup):
        print(entry)
        writer.writerow(entry)
```

The generated CSV ends up looking like e.g.

```
paragraph,title,link
"The mayor of Helao Nafidi, Elias Nghipangelwa, has expressed disappointment after Covid-19 relief food was stolen and sold by two security officers entrusted to guard the warehouse where the food was stored.","Guards arrested for theft of relief food",https://neweralive.na/posts/posts/guards-arrested-for-theft-of-relief-food
"Government has decided to construct 1 200 affordable homes, starting Thursday this week.","Govt to construct  1 200 low-cost houses",https://neweralive.na/posts/posts/govt-to-construct-1-200-low-cost-houses
...
```

Comment: There are heroes in this world. Thank you so much.

Comment: Hi there - wow this is just overwhelming i like this solution - it is a cristal clear csv-example in python. Many thanks for this!

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas module and convert dataframe-table to csv easily.

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq

page_url = "https://neweralive.na/today/"

ne_url = "https://neweralive.na/posts/"

uClient = uReq(page_url)

page_soup = soup(uClient.read(), "html.parser")

uClient.close()

containers = page_soup.findAll("article", {"class": "post-item"})

filename = "newera.csv"

rows = []  # Initialize list of list which is converted to dataframe.

for container in containers:

    paragraph_container = container.findAll("p", {"class": "post-excerpt"})
    paragraph = paragraph_container[0].text

    title_container = container.findAll("h3", {"class": "post-title"})
    title = title_container[0].text
    weblink = ne_url + title_container[0].a["href"]
    
    rows.append([paragraph, title, weblink])  # each row is appended 

df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns = ["paragraph","title","link"])  # col-name is headers 

df.to_csv(filename, index=None)
```

Comment: This is a task that absolutely does not require Pandas.

Comment: I agree. Just an alternative.

Comment: dear Shimo - many thanks for showing up the options and possibliities that we have with Pandas - I like it - the idea of having various ways and paths that all we have. This makes Python so powerful! So thank you for steppin up the plate with your ideas